# ssh session with proxycommand keeps hanging on CentOS 7

Tags: ssh, proxy, centos7

I am using a CentOS 7.3.1611 box as an ssh proxy server. Connecting to the proxy server itself works fine and the connection stays open and alive for hours.

Proxying an ssh connection via this server results in the session hanging after about a minute.

`CLIENT ---> SSH-PROXY` works.

`CLIENT ---> SSH-PROXY ---> FOO-SERVER` keeps hanging after a few seconds.

I am using these settings in my clients `.ssh/config`:

```
Host *
    ServerAliveInterval 30

Host SSH-PROXY
    HostName EXTERNAL_IP
    Port 22
    User root

Host FOO-SERVER
  proxycommand ssh PROXYSERVER -W 10.1.2.3:22
  User root
```

on the client I can reach out to `FOO-SERVER` using:

`ssh FOO-SERVER`

I already tried setting:

```
TCPKeepAlive yes
ClientAliveInterval 60
```

in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` without any sucess.

What could be the issue here? (The connection to the server itself is rock stable. The exact setup works flawlessly when using Ubuntu 16.04.1 as the proxy server os).

Comment: *I already tried setting: ...* on the proxy server?

Comment: Hangs after exactly the same number of seconds each time, or is random?

Comment: @Aaron seems to be an exact number.

Comment: @Jakuje I also tried setting it both on the proxy.

Comment: When using ssh on the proxy itself, the connections also time out after a certain amount of time. There is no firewall in between as well as the network connection is persistent throughout the whole time.

Comment: How long does it take to hang?

Comment: about 20 seconds.